# Что делает и для чего нужно return? js

Tags: javascript, функции

Всем привет, на момент обучения столкнулся с проблемой. Что делает return и для чего оно нужно вообще? Читаю объяснение в книге, смотрю на ютубе и всё равно не понимаю, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Оператор `return` завершает работу функции и возвращает из нее значение

**Пример**:

```
function foo()
{
    return 1;
    
    var n = 1; // Эта часть кода уже не будет выполнена, так как возврат из функции был выше
  
}
```

Comment: а куда возвращает значение?

Comment: @Darkness, в место вызова

Answer (score 0):

return:

1. Останавливает функцию, т.е. её выполнение прекращается
2. Возвращает что-либо

Пример:

```js
function calc(first, second) {
    return first + second; // Возвращает сложение двух переданных аргументов
}

let res = calc(23, 24);

console.log(res) // 47
```

Comment: а куда возвращает то?

Comment: Например, как показано в моем ответе, если переменной присвоить функцию(именно `calc()`, а не `calc`), а переменную вывести в консоль, то мы получим сложение двух переданных аргументов (23 и 24), а не саму функцию.

Comment: грубо говоря, если присвоить функцию переменной, то переменная будет равна тому, что было возвращено, а не самой функции.

Comment: `= calc()` — присваивается "результат вызова функции" (оно же - то, что вернет return), а не "функция")

Comment: я так и написал, просто указал, что если бы было `= calc`, то переменная была бы равна функции.